# Minikube on Windows 10 with Hyper-V stuck on "Starting cluster components"

Tags: kubernetes, windows-10, hyper-v, minikube

I'm using minikube on windows 10 and trying to start it using Hyper-V.
Because I'm behind a corporate proxy and use CNTLM to avoid authentication. I added the http_proxy and https_proxy as docker env.

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "PrimaryVirtualSwitch" --docker-env http_proxy=http://10.55.35.143:3128 --docker-env https_proxy=http://10.55.35.143:3128 --memory 8192 --cpus 4
```

The output is the following:

> Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
>   Starting VM...
>   Getting VM IP address...
>   Moving files into cluster...
>   Setting up certs...
>   Connecting to cluster...
>   Setting up kubeconfig...
>   Starting cluster components...

At the last step "Starting cluster components" the command stucks.

I tried to enable verbose output but it doesn't log anything after reaching the "Starting cluster components" step.

The command `minikube ssh` is working and I can ping `10.55.35.143:3128`.

Could anyone give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

**Additional Information**
Minikube version: v0.28.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [cmder](http://cmder.net/), type bash to switch to bash, export http_proxy and https_proxy and run minikube start. 
You can find more information about the related topic at https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2425.

You may also try to launch minikube with `--bootstrapper=localkube` option.

Comment: I already tried this. My Problem is not the downloading of the iso. This works fine behind the proxy. As you can see in the output I posted I'm over the step where files are downloaded.

Comment: What version of minikube are you using?
Have you tried to launch minikibe with "--bootstrapper=localkube" option as described https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/2791 and https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2765 ?

Comment: I use version v0.28.0. I didn't try localkube. I will when I'm at the computer the next time.

Comment: thank you for the hint to use bootstrapper=localkube. This worked :) Add this to your answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck "Starting cluster components..."
After a lot of retries I found out in some github issue that I have to add the global system variable MINIKUBE_HOME and then it worked. The variable has to point to the path where minikube.exe is installed.

```
MINIKUBE_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Kubernetes\Minikube
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution. Unfortunately i cant verify it anymore since i switched to the kubernetes integration of docker for windows. They provide a one node kubernetes cluster aswell and it worked out of the box